# Elabel undefined error in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I have been porting a script I have from V2 to V3 and I have hit a snag. I am getting an Elabel undefined error but I am not sure why I am getting this. I have updated the Elabel.js to V3 which is here...[ELABLE.JS](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/elabel2.js) I am not sure if this is not a good copy of ELabel.js or what. I have tried a couple of different other copies with no success.

Here is the working example of it using V2

[V2 EXAMPLE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/NSGMap/NSGMap.php)

Here is the V3 example. As you can see in V3 the range rings are not drawn and the map doesn't update and the table doesn't populate. I know it is related to the ELabel.js but I am not sure why and I can't find the issue to why I am getting the undefined error. I know it is related to this because when I remove the script include for the ELable.js I have the same problems on V2 that I am seeing on V3.

[V3 EXAMPLE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxgmap_lightning.php)

Since the code is too long to post here, the link to the relevant code is in the link below. Line 135 is where the ELabel error is coming from. This worked great in V2 but not V3. So I don't know if I am overlooking something that has changed in V2 to V3.

[EXAMPLE CODE](http://codepad.org/L4n5syU6)

So can anyone offer any insight on why I am getting this undefined error and shed some light on what I may be doing wrong and overlooking?

-Thanks

Comment: The whole page looks like it was written a good decade ago and could do with a makeover. The global namespace is well used, and jQuery is included but it's hardly used - many functions will greatly simplify. The actual problem has got to be scope or load order. As ELabel is defined in the global namespace, it's unlikely to be scope. It's not obviously load order either but you might try moving `<script src="elabel2.js" ...>` into the document head. The big script from 621 to 947 should also be in the head (cautiously).

Comment: Also, take a look at `updateHTML()`. How many times is  `resp.split("|")` called when the array has already been assigned to `result`?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Yes the code was written several years ago. I did not write it. I am only trying to update it the best I can with what I know. So I don't have much background on it. I have moved some things around and organized the order better but I am still getting the error. Here is the updated map code [nsgmap.js](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/nsgmap.js) and here is the full page [V3 Map](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxgmap_lightning.php) One thing to note I can get the Elabel error to go away changing order but then I get a llcetner not defined. I can't figure this out.

Comment: Texan, the block of six `doDrawCircle()` commands isn't inside a function. Try moving it inside `initialize()`. `UpdateKML();` too.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot thanks for the suggestion I made those changes. I am making progress as the table is now populating with data since doing that. I am now getting a "Map is undefined" regarding this line `map.removeOverlay(nyLayer);` It's suppose to draw range rings and also count down and auto update the map with new data. Look at my V2 Example vs V3 Example in my original post. V2 is how it's suppose to work. This is the updated code [nsgmap.js](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/nsgmap.js) What is causing that error. I am sure it is what's causing the remaining two issues.

Comment: You now have the block of calls to `doDrawCircle()` inside the `doDrawCircle` function definition, which will lead to infinite recursion (stack full error). In the V2 code that block, together with a call to `UpdateKML()` is inside `initialize()`.

Comment: Also, you are using the dreaded `with()`, which (most javascript programmers generally avoid](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot thanks, I moved the `doDrawCircle()` inside the `initialize()` as I misunderstood your previous suggestion. I am still getting the same error in Firebug and 3 new ones in Chrome. I didn't write this script so I am not familiar with it or with javascript. I am just trying to port it to V3 so it will still work. I am not sure why I am getting these errors as the map is working now and the code related to it isn't related to the Google API, at least I don't think it is. I am trying but, can you show me an example please so I know if I am doing this correctly?

Comment: I can't get a local version working - there are too many external dependencies that won't download - so can't really advise properly, much as I would like to.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot if you could offer an example of what you're referring to that's really all I need. I don't need a working example. That base code is [NSGMAP.js](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/nsgmap.js) I am getting an error referring to this line `map.removeOverlay(nyLayer);`

Comment: Texan, I've got something working but the news is not good. I'm having to track down bug after bug. I've fixed maybe 15 of them and still going.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot that's the same thing I am running into. I have been searching the web for solutions for hours but there seems like there are 100 different ways and none of them fit what I need. What ever you got would be helpful as I am banging my head against the wall.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot the issue is related to this code as it is depreciated. `// add back overlays
 map.removeOverlay(nyLayer);     // Remove overlays
 nyLayer = new KmlLayer(URLToKML + "?rand="+(new Date()).valueOf() );  // rand is used to trick google maps into thinking this is a new KML (don't use cache version)
 map.addOverlay(nyLayer);     // Add the new data from the newly generated KML` but I haven't been able to find a solution to resolve this with current code. That is where my error is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Texan, here's te script from my local file, which is working as far as getting the circles and labels to show. All ajax aspects are untested.

The script below should be pasted into the document head, immediately before the closing `</head>` tag.

This replaces various other inline scripts. The only remaining scripts in the document body should be the google analytics (2 scripts) and StatCounter (1 script). No external scripts should be removed.

```
<script>
var map;

jQuery(function($) {
    var llCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(32.8297,-96.6486);
    var URLToKML = 'http://www.mesquiteweather.net/NSGMap/GMStrikes.kml';
    var Sec2Update = 30;
    var KMLdate = 1372820133;
    //var NSdate = 1372927434;
    var NSdate = 0; //Force KML file creation on first update
    var TZString = 'CDT';
    var TZOffset = -5;

    var nyLayer;
    var lcolor = 'white';//This defines the line color for the target circle

    //Check if user wants debug mode
    dbg = (gup('dbg')=='y') ? 'y' : 'n';
    var force = (gup('force')=='y') ? 'y' : 'n';  //Force updates regardless of NSStrikes.txt date

    var mapReady = false;

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: llCenter,
            panControl: false,
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            },
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        var radarOptions = {
            gmap: map,
            name: 'Radar',
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
            action: function(){
                if (map.overlayMapTypes.length==0) {
                    map.overlayMapTypes.push(null); // create empty overlay entry
                    map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("1", tileNEX);
                }
                else {
                    map.overlayMapTypes.clear();
                }
            }
        }
        var radarButton = new buttonControl(radarOptions);
        tileNEX = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
                return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime();
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            opacity: 0.70,
            name: 'NEXRAD',
            isPng: true
        });

        function MyLogoControl() {
            var logo = $('<img/>').attr('src', 'images/watermark_MW_GMap.png').css('cursor', 'pointer').get(0);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(logo, 'click', function() {
                window.location = 'http://www.mesquiteweather.net';
            });
            return logo;
        }
        var logoControlDiv = $('<div/>').css('padding','5px').append(MyLogoControl()).get(0);
        logoControlDiv.index = 0; // used for ordering
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(logoControlDiv);
        var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(URLToKML + "?rand=" + (new Date()).valueOf(), {
            suppressInfoWindows: false,
            map: map,
            preserveViewport: true
        });

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
            //You can add circles, or change other parameters
            //radials should be set to true for the maximum distance if you want radials
            //doDrawCircle(circleUnits, center, circleRadius, lineColor, lineWidth, lineOpacity, fillColor, fillOpacity, opts, radials)
            doDrawCircle('MI', llCenter,  62, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI', llCenter, 124, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI', llCenter, 187, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI', llCenter, 249, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI', llCenter, 312, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            doDrawCircle('MI', llCenter, 374, lcolor, 1, .7, "#FFFF00", 0, { clickable: false }, false);
            //doDrawCircle('MI', llCenter, 374, lcolor, 1, .7, '#00FF00', 0, { clickable: false }, true);   // This would add the radials

            UpdateKML();//Get the first set of data
        });
    }

    //Function to draw circles
    function doDrawCircle(circleUnits, center, circleRadius, liColor, liWidth, liOpa, fillColor, fillOpa, opts, radials) {
        var polyLineOptions = {
            map: map,
            path: null,//added with jQuery.extend()
            strokeColor: liColor,
            strokeOpacity: liOpa,
            strokeWeight: liWidth
        };
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var circlePoints = [];
        var d = circleRadius / ((circleUnits == 'KM') ? 6378.8 : 3963.189);
        var d2r = Math.PI/180;
        var lat1 = d2r * center.lat();//radians
        var lng1 = d2r * center.lng();//radians
        for (var a=0; a<361; a++ ) {
            var tc = d2r * a;
            var sin_lat1 = Math.sin(lat1),
                cos_lat1 = Math.cos(lat1),
                sin_d = Math.sin(d),
                cos_d = Math.cos(d),
                sin_tc = Math.sin(tc),
                cos_tc = Math.cos(tc);
            var y = Math.asin(sin_lat1 * cos_d + cos_lat1 * sin_d * cos_tc);
            var dlng = Math.atan2(sin_tc * sin_d * cos_lat1, cos_d - sin_lat1 * Math.sin(y));
            var x = ((lng1 - dlng + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI)) - Math.PI ; // MOD function
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(y/d2r, x/d2r);
            circlePoints.push(point);
            bounds.extend(point);
            if(a==0) {
                var offset = new google.maps.Size((circleRadius < 100) ? -5 : -8, 0);
                //ELabel(map, point, html, classname, pixelOffset, percentOpacity, isFloatShadow, overlap);
                var label = new ELabel(map, point, circleRadius, "style1", offset, 100, false);
                label.setMap(map);
            }
            if (radials && ((a==0) || (a==45) || (a==90) || (a==135) || (a==180) || (a==225) || (a==270) || (a==315))) {
                new google.maps.Polyline($.extend({}, polyLineOptions, {
                    path: [center, point]
                }));
            }
        }
        new google.maps.Polyline($.extend({}, polyLineOptions, {
            path: circlePoints
        }));
        map.fitBounds(bounds);//This sets the map bounds to be as big as the target circles, comment out if you don't want it
    }

    //This function is called on page load to start the refresh of the strikes
    function cycle() {
        setInterval(CountDown, 1000);
    }
    var intvl = Sec2Update;

    function CountDown() {
        intvl -= 1;
        if(intvl < 1) {
            intvl = Sec2Update;
            UpdateKML();
        }
        $("#cntdwn").html(intvl);
    }

    //This calls genkml.php on every refresh cycle to generate a new kml file
    function UpdateKML() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'genkml.php',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                force: force,
                ofd: KMLdate,
                nsd: NSdate, 
                dbg: dbg
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: '',//????
        }).done(function(resp, textStatus) {
            var $debugDiv = $("#div1");
            if (dbg == 'y') {//Check if we want debug info
                if (!$debugDiv.length) {//Check if debug div exists, if not add it to end of body
                    $debugDiv = $("<div/>").attr('id', 'div1').appendTo('body');
                }
                var tmpresp = resp || ' ';
                $debugDiv.html('Response Status: ' + textStatus + '<br />' + tmpresp);
            } else {//Else empty the debug div
                $debugDiv.empty();
            }
            var dates = resp.split("|")[0].split("~");
            KMLdate = dates[0];
            NSdate = dates[1];
            updateHTML(resp);//This calls the updateHTML function if info was returned
        });

        if(map) {
            if(nyLayer) {
                map.removeOverlay(nyLayer); //Remove overlays
            }

            //nyLayer = new KmlLayer(URLToKML + "?rand="+(new Date()).valueOf() );
            nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(URLToKML + "?rand=" + (new Date()).valueOf(), {
                suppressInfoWindows: false,
                map: map,
                preserveViewport: true
            });
        }
        // Time overlayed on map - could be in updateHTML() to just show when .kml read last
        $('#currenttime').innerHTML = CurrentTime ("B", "12a", true, TZOffset);
    }

    function CurrentTime (type, hours, secs, ofs) {
        /*
        type (char)           hours (char)      secs (bool)     ofs (num)
        "U"-UTC               "24"=24 hr time   true=hh:mm:ss   0=hours from UTC
        "B"-User's Browser    "12"=12 hr time   false=hh:mm
        "S"-Web Site          "12a"=am/pm
        */
        if (type  == null){ type  = "B"; }     // These are the defaults
        if (hours == null){ hours = "12a"; }
        if (secs  == null){ secs  = true; }
        if (ofs   == null){ ofs   = 0; }
        var currentHour = 0;
        var currentMinute = 0;
        var currentSecond = 0;
        var time = [];
        var currentDate = new Date();

        if (type == "U") {
            currentHour = currentDate.getUTCHours();// UTC
        } else if (type == "B") {
            currentHour = currentDate.getHours();// Viewer's time
        } else {
            currentHour = currentDate.getUTCHours() + ofs;// your local time
            if(currentHour < 0) { currentHour = currentHour + 24;}
        }

        currentMinute = currentDate.getMinutes();
        currentMinute = (currentMinute < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinute;

        if (hours == "24") {
            if(currentHour == 24) { currentHour = 0 };// use if wanting 24 hour time
            currentHour = (currentHour < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentHour;
        } else if (hours == "12") {
            if(currentHour == 0) currentHour = 12;
            currentHour = (currentHour < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentHour;
        } else {
            if(currentHour == 0) currentHour = 12;// else no leading zero for am/pm
        }

        time.push(currentHour, currentMinute);

        if (secs) {
            currentSecond = currentDate.getSeconds();
            currentSecond = (currentSecond < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSecond;
            time.push(currentSecond);
        }

        time = time.join(' : ');

        if(hours == "12a") {
            time = time + " " + (currentHour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM");
        }
        return time;
    }

    //This function is only used if you leave the debug checkbox below
    //  You can remove this function and the checkbox and set the debug
    //  mode using the dbg=y query parameter
    function debug(obj){
        if (obj.checked) {
            dbg = 'y';
        } else {
            dbg = 'n';
            $('#div1').empty();
        }
    }
    //This function is only used if you leave the Force Update checkbox below
    //  You can remove this function and the checkbox and set the force
    //  mode using the force=y query parameter
    function forceupdate(obj) {
        force = (obj.checked) ? 'y' : 'n';
    }
    //This function parses out the query parameter value
    function gup( name ) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
        var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
        return results ? results[1] : "";
    }
    /*
    You can add custom HTML code here and get access to the additional data that is returned everytime the page calls genkml.php.  
    In the example below, result is an array that holds 16 values (17, if in debug mode) with each of the values explained below.
    */
    function updateHTML(resp) {
        var result = resp.split("|");
        if (result.length < 16) return;//Make sure there is data
        document.getElementById('q1').innerHTML = result[1];//Number of strikes in first quarter of diplay time
        document.getElementById('q2').innerHTML = result[2];//Number of strikes in second quarter of diplay time
        document.getElementById('q3').innerHTML = result[3];//Number of strikes in third quarter of diplay time
        document.getElementById('q4').innerHTML = result[4];//Number of strikes in fourth quarter of diplay time
        document.getElementById('numicp').innerHTML = result[6];//Number of IC+ strikes
        document.getElementById('numicn').innerHTML = result[5];//Number of IC- strikes
        document.getElementById('numcgp').innerHTML = result[7];//Number of CG+ strikes
        document.getElementById('numcgn').innerHTML = result[8];//Number of CG- strikes
        document.getElementById('ds').innerHTML = result[9];//Total displayed strikes
        document.getElementById('ta').innerHTML = result[10];//Total strikes in NSStrikes
        document.getElementById('dt').innerHTML = result[11];//Display time
        document.getElementById('numicpd').innerHTML = result[13];//Number of IC+ strikes
        document.getElementById('numicnd').innerHTML = result[12];//Number of IC- strikes
        document.getElementById('numcgpd').innerHTML = result[14];//Number of CG+ strikes
        document.getElementById('numcgnd').innerHTML = result[15];//Number of CG- strikes
        document.getElementById('tu').innerHTML = Date();//Number of CG- strikes
        document.getElementById('sec2up').innerHTML = Sec2Update;//Number of CG- strikes
        var dt = result[11] / 4;
        document.getElementById('q1t').innerHTML = [0, dt].split('-');//Set time frame headers
        document.getElementById('q2t').innerHTML = [dt, 2*dt].split('-');
        document.getElementById('q3t').innerHTML = [2*dt, 3*dt].split('-');
        document.getElementById('q4t').innerHTML = [3*dt, dt].split('-');
    }

    //Onload event caller. Does not intefere with OnLoad event in Body tag.
    //Put this is after all functions to be called
    function addLoadEvent(func) {
        $(window).on('load', func);
    }

    initialize();
    FADING_SCROLLER.changecontent();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/***********************************************
* Fading Scroller- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************
* Wrapped as module by Beetroot-Beetroot
* Converted to use jQuery calls by Beetroot-Beetroot
* Note: The "proper" approach would be to use the 'color' jQuery plugin
***********************************************/
var FADING_SCROLLER = (function($) {//Module patttern
    var delay = 5000; //set delay between message change (in miliseconds)
    var maxsteps = 10; //number of steps to take to change from start color to endcolor
    var stepdelay = 200; //time in miliseconds of a single step
    //**Note: maxsteps*stepdelay will be total time in miliseconds of fading effect
    var startcolor = [201,201,201]; //start color (red, green, blue)
    var endcolor = [0,0,0]; //end color (red, green, blue)
    var fadelinks = 1;  //should links inside scroller content also fade like text? 0 for no, 1 for yes.

    // *** No need to edit below this line ***
    var faderdelay = 0;
    var index = 0;

    function changecontent() {
        var $fscroller = $("#fscroller").css('color', "rgb(" + startcolor.join(', ') + ")");
        var $content = $fscroller.find(".NWSinfo div").hide().eq(index).show().end();
        if(fadelinks) linkcolorchange(1);
        colorfade(1, 15);
        index = (index + 1) % $content.length;
    }

    function linkcolorchange(step) {
        $("#fscroller a").each(function() {
            $(this).css('color', getstepcolor(step));
        });
    }

    // Rafael Raposo edited function
    var fadecounter;
    function colorfade(step) {
        if(step<=maxsteps) {    
            $("#fscroller").css('color', getstepcolor(step));
            if (fadelinks)
                linkcolorchange(step);
            step++;
            fadecounter = setTimeout(function() {
                colorfade(step);
            }, stepdelay);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(fadecounter);
            $("#fscroller").css('color', "rgb(" + endcolor.join(', ') + ")");
            setTimeout(changecontent, delay);
        }
    }
    //Rafael Raposo's new function
    function getstepcolor(step) {
      var diff, newcolor = [];
      for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        diff = startcolor[i] - endcolor[i];
        if(diff > 0) {
           newcolor[i] = startcolor[i] - (Math.round((diff/maxsteps)) * step);
        } else {
           newcolor[i] = startcolor[i] + (Math.round((Math.abs(diff)/maxsteps)) * step);
        }
      }
      return "rgb(" + newcolor.join(', ') + ")";
    }

    // *** Expose public methods here ***
    return {
        changecontent: changecontent
    };
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I only changed the javascript, not the CSS or HTML. Some comments are included but not really enough considering the scope of the changes.

You will see I wrapped the main script in a `$(function(){...})` structure and the Fading Scroller script as a Module. This was done to prevent polluting the global namespace and the possibility of contamination between scripts. I left `map` in the global namespace in case it's needed in any of the other scripts.

I also made some changes to a local copy of `ajaxWDwx.js` but I don't think any of them are relevant.

Comment: @Beetroo-Beetroot Thanks! I know that took some time and you didn't have to go through all that trouble. The rings look great. Let me play with this and see if I can intergrated it with what I have working so far. When you viewed the page you viewed the raw source. Here is how it is laid out. [ExAMPLE](http://codepad.org/OPgG7DWg) That's why I was saying that NSGMAP.js was strictly the map code for that script because I included it in the head with script tags. Keeps things cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: Texan, once I started I was determined to get a result. Yes you will have to update all your original files as appropriate. It's probably best to regard my code as a suite of ideas on which you can draw.

Comment: @Beetroo-Beetroot Ha! yes I understand it's a challenge once you get started. Gmaps has been a steep learning curve for me so I understand. Thank you so much, this will be a huge help and give me something to play with and some guidance. I will let you know how it works out. I am playing with it now.